# Kotlin coroutine flow return first result while continuing operation

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have an Android app with a local DB with movies in it (title, genre, recommended) and a backend with the same structure to let the user can set a movie to be recommended on a web platform.

In my app I want to allow the user to fetch the first movie recommended for a specific genre, while at the same time update the recommended boolean in the local DB (for future offline filtering).

I am handling it with Flow and coroutines as such:

```kotlin
fun getFirstRecommendedMovie(genre: String): Movie {
   val movies = dao.getMovies(genre)
   val recommendedMovies = movies.filter{ movie ->
      endpoint.isMovieRecommended(movie).single()
   }
   dao.updateRecommendedMovies(recommendedMovies).single()
   return recommendedMovies[0]
}

private class Endpoint {
   // HTTP request to fetch whether the given movie is recommended or not
   fun isMovieRecommended(movie: Movie): Flow<Boolean>
}

private class Dao {
   // Returns alphabetically ordered movies from a specific genre
   fun getMovies(genre: String): Flow<List<Movie>>
   // Updates the recommended field of movies in the DB
   fun updateRecommendedMovies(movies: List<Movie>): Flow<Unit>
}
```

The problem is that to return the movie to the user I need to wait for the loop of all `isMovieRecommended` from the back end, and this can take a lot of time.

Is there a way to do the whole "remote loop calls" + "db update" while at the same time return the first movie coming as "recommended" from the endpoint to the user?

p.s. I have no way to modify the endpoint request to return a list of recommended movies and the check needs to be one by one

Comment: This is not a direct answer to the quesiton, but it seems you misunderstand the usage of `Flow` here. Why does `isMovieRecommended()` return a flow? If you use it for a single value, it should just be a `suspend` function returning a boolean. Same question for `updateRecommendedMovies` which should just be a simple suspend function with implicit `Unit` return type. As for `getMovies`, it should either be a `suspend` function returning a list, or a function returning a `Flow<Movie>`.

Comment: Generally speaking, you would need to start asynchronous operation here. Then, you need to watch out for multiple `getFirstRecommendedMovie()` starting multiple background tasks, modifying the same data. But honestly, I don't really think you should do any of this. It doesn't seem right that the function that is supposed to just get first recommended movie actually does much more and it even starts background processing. It would be pretty misleading for the user of this function.

Comment: Also, it would mean that after returning from the function, movie is still not marked locally as recommended, which may lead to unpredictable behavior somewhere else in the code.

Comment: Is the backend not in your control? Or why can't you modify the endpoint? @broot's points are all valid, but I think the main problem is the backend. It seems very unpractical to me to have an endpoint for just checking if a single movie is recommended. I would expect either an endpoint that returns all recommended movies, or just a list of all movies where you can check a recommended flag in the client, or an endpoint where you can provide a list of movies to check them for being recommended.

Comment: I agree with @broot here, I think you should decouple the update of recommended movies in DB from the access of the first recommended movie. Or you might design a more advanced system that returns immediately based on the state of the DB if the data is fresh, or updates the DB on demand if the last access was too long ago, and waits in that case like you do now.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers.
I do not have control on the back end unfortunately, and if I did it would still be very lengthy to do get a change in there :( 
Other than that the use of Flow even for simple "mono value" results is to make the steps throughout the app homogeneous (this is an excerpt just for simplicity) for all that goes to endpoints or DAOs relies on Flows

Comment: Using `Flow` for eveything might feel simpler when you begin using coroutines, but honestly it feels pretty weird (and overly complex) for someone who is used to it. It's like saying returning `List<T>` from every function is simpler than returning `T` for single values and `List<T>` for multiple values :)